# Syntax Error in noflo example

Tags: node.js, noflo

The [NoFlo Documentation](http://noflojs.org/documentation/) has a
section titled "Defining your first graph" and it states that making a
directory, defining a graph in that directory and then calling `noflo`
on that graph should execute successfully.

However, in my case I get a syntax error:

```
tbrannon@tbrannon0:~/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project$ ./node_modules/.bin/noflo --debug graphs/ShowContents.fbp 

/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo-filesystem/components/ReadFile.coffee:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { # The ReadFile c
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at ComponentLoader.load (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/ComponentLoader.js:127:26)
  at Network.load (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/Network.js:113:26)
  at Network.addNode (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/Network.js:135:19)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/Network.js:202:37
  at Network.connect (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/Network.js:214:14)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/NoFlo.js:55:22
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:132:16
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:758:21
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:152:18
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Docments/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:39:16
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:758:21
  at ComponentLoader.getModuleComponents (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:61:16)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/lib/nodejs/ComponentLoader.js:146:22
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:118:5
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at cb (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:14
  at asyncMap (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:27:18)
  at next (/usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:200:5)
  at /usr/local/g7/home/tbrannon/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project/node_modules/noflo/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:157:7
  at LOOP (fs.js:1356:14)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

tbrannon@tbrannon0:~/Documents/Programming/noflo/my-noflo-example-project$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by an [API change in CoffeeScript 1.7](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog). [A fix](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/pull/132) was made in NoFlo's git repository.

The fix was included in [NoFlo 0.4.4](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/blob/master/CHANGES.md#044-february-4th-2014) available via NPM.